# Как настроить редирект в .htaccess для динамических урл

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, редирект

Как в .htaccess прописать редирект, типа:
где есть параметр ?p=2, перенаправлять на ?page=2

**Пример, перенаправлять с такого типа страниц:**

site.com/category?p=2

**перенаправлять на**

site.com/category?page=2

Comment: Вот так пробую 
`RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)?p=(0-9*)$ /site.com/$1?page=$2 [R=301,L] `
не работает

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу на свой вопрос решением

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(\d+)

RewriteRule (.*) $1?page=%1